# i dont want select2 multi select drop down loose data in page refresh. select2 drop down should maintain state

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I don't want `select2` multi select drop down loose data in page refresh. `select2` drop down should maintain state

below is my code. its working fine, I have only problem that `select2` is losing selection/data if we refresh the page.My requirement is even after page refresh it should not remove there values/or empty.

```js
 $processOrderNbr.select2({
            ajax: getProcessOrderNbr(),
            minimumInputLength: 4,
            placeholder: " ",
            allowClear: false,
            multiple: true
        });

        function getProcessOrderNbr() {
            return {
                url: 'GetProcessOrder',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        searchKeyword: params
                    };
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                text: item,
                                id: item
                            }
                        })
                    };
                }
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put them again into the `select2` boxes.
I had a similar issue, where I work with `window.sessionStorage` to store the selected values. After reloading the page, I set the values stored in the session storage into the `select2` boxes with this code:

```
var selectionList = [{ id: window.sessionStorage.getItem("searchValue"), text: window.sessionStorage.getItem("searchValue")}];
$("#searchValue").select2({
                data: selectionList
});
$('#searchValue').val(window.sessionStorage.getItem("searchValue")).trigger("change");
```

To store the values in the `window.sessionStorage` you can use this code:

```
$('#searchValue').select2({
...
.on("change", function (e) {
  window.sessionStorage.setItem("searchValue", $(this).val());
}
...
```

Maybe this solution helps you in your case, but someone knows a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show the previous wrote value after **reloading** the page without losing the data that is the solution.

```
var dataCategory = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('category'));
var select = $("#category");

select.select2({
    tags: true,
    allowClear: true,
    maximumInputLength: 30,
    maximumSelectionLength: 20,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    data: dataCategory 
}).on("change", function (e) {

    var selected = []; // create an array to hold all currently wrote by user

    // loop through each option
    $('#category option').each(function() {
        // if it's selected, add it to the array above
        if (this.selected) {
            selected.push(this.value);
        }
    });


    // store the array of selected options
    sessionStorage.setItem('category', JSON.stringify(selected));

});


// set and show the previous wrote keywords
var dataCategoryLength = dataCategory.length;
for (var i =0; i < dataCategoryLength; i++) {
    $('#category').val(dataCategory).trigger('change');

}
```